# XPath for ImportXML in Gsheet

Tags: xpath, import, google-sheets

I am trying to use ImportXML in Google spreadsheet and got NA result. Error message:

> Import XML content can't be parsed
>   URL: http://www.tripadvisor.com/Hotel_Review-g293916-d309884-Reviews-Indra_Regent_Hotel-Bangkok.html

This what I have:

```
importxml(url, "//img[@class='sprite-rating_rr_fill rating_rr_fill rr35']/@content")
```

That is what I want to grab:
[the content attribute value of img](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0pViF.png)

I am looking forward to your advice. I am not sure what I am doing wrong.

Comment: sounds like you are trying to use an xml parser on badly formatted html. maybe google spreadsheets has an `importhtml` function you can use instead?

Comment: @KeithHall, Thanks for your response. Unfortunately, the importhtml function is only support for table and list tag.

Answer (score 0):

It's not your xpath that is wrong, rather is the source that is not a proper xml document (the img tag is not closed).

indeed, if you try to run:

```
  =IMPORTXML( url, "//div[@class='rs rating']" )
```

it resolves to:

```
 1,087 Reviews.
```

But any descendant of it will throw an error.
You could try pass the html source through a 'sanitizer' first, then it should work.

Comment: Thanks for the response, but I want to take the rating. (3.5). Sorry, may I know hot to sanitize the html source?

Comment: html sanitizing is not a small task. you will not be able to consume the html directly from tripadvisor, but you will either need to save the html locally, invoke the sanitizer on it, and then invoke the import function in your google sheet or you will need to set up a proxy service that will do the sanitize for you. In either case is not something completely trivial. Have a look at http://jsoup.org/ , and https://www.npmjs.com/package/sanitize-html . As last resort, you could apply some regex to fix the img tag to the html before using importxml

Comment: I've taken a closer look at the source page you are trying to parse and I see that there are plenty of non closed tags etc. Rather than try scraping a malformed page, did you consider using the Tripadvisor api? (https://developer-tripadvisor.com/content-api/)

Comment: Thanks for your advice. Unfortunately, to register on Tripadvisor api, required active URL, which I don't have. However, I did it using php.